# Разница между запуском модуля как сценария и запуск импортированием

Tags: python

Есть два циклических сценария на питоне из известной книги:

recur1:

```
x = 1
import recur2
y = 2
```

recur2:

```
from recur1 import x
from recur1 import y
```

Я не понимаю, почему, если запускать recur1 как сценарий, никаких ошибок нет, но если recur1 импортировать в интерактивном режиме, то получаем ошибку, поскольку в пространстве имен y ещё не определено.

Для меня важно понять тонкую грань между способами запуска модуля.

С зеркальной стороны, если импортировать recur2 в интерактивном сеансе, то ошибки нет. Если запустить recur2 как сценарий - та же ошибка.

Comment: Укажите точный текст ошибки

Comment: `Я не понимаю, почему, если запускать recur1 как сценарий, никаких ошибок нет` - все прекрасно падает: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNAyZ.png Тут никакой тонкой разницы нет, никогда не нужно делать рекуривные импорты.

Comment: хм, у меня не падает: питон 3.11.2

Comment: https://ru.paste.pics/QJCM5

Comment: Даже если у вас каким-то чудом не упало, полагаться на это не стоит, и пытаться провернуть какие-то трюки с циклическим импортом не нужно. Вот Python 3.11.8: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YfWO.png

Comment: Я согласен с Вами на счет трюков. Тут дело в желании разобраться в разнице между запусками модуля. Исходя из книги, запуск сценария и импорт модуля не совсем одно и то же. Кроме того, что при импортировании создается объект модуля (что понятно), есть видимо ещё какие-то нюансы в обработке кода (я могу ошибаться). Но вот recur2 импортируется без ошибок. По этому поводу из книги в след. комментарии...

Comment: импортирование модуля recur2 первым работает из-за того, что рекурсивная операция импортирования из recurl в recur2 извлекает recur2 как единое целое вместо получения специфических имен. Модуль recur2 является незавершенным, когда он импортируется из recurl, но поскольку в нем используется оператор import, а не from, все проходит благополучно: Python находит и возвращает уже созданный объект модуля recur2 и продолжает выполнять остаток модуля recurl без каких-либо затруднений.

Comment: В Python 3.12.2 у меня тоже не отваливается recur1 как сценарий

Comment: То что у вас благополучно запуск recur1.py работает - это "счастливая" случайность. Полагаться на это нельзя. Тут нет смысла пытаться найти какой-то глубинный смысл или пытаться как-то применить это на практике. На этом я заканчиваю этот диалог.